# iOS: adding key/value to multidimentional array at specific index

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm pretty new in iOS dev. Basically I have a multidimensional array as per below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
  (
  [Name] => Peter
  [Gender] => Male
  )
[1] => Array
  (
  [Name] => Glenn
  [Gender] => Female
  )
[2] => Array
  (
  [Name] => Richard
  [Gender] => Male
  )
)
```

At some point, I am going to add in additional key/value at certain index. Take for example, I am adding a new entry at index 1 at the end of the array(the sequence is not something to bother actually, it can fit in front or at the end) with `[Location] => Japan`

As such, the array should looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
  (
  [Name] => Peter
  [Gender] => Male
  )
[1] => Array
  (
  [Name] => Glenn
  [Gender] => Female
  [Location] => Japan
  )
[2] => Array
  (
  [Name] => Richard
  [Gender] => Male
  )
)
```

How can I achieve that? Pls inspect my code below as I really have no idea as every attempt results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS or app being terminated. Thanks in advance, Jason.

```
for(int x=0; x<[arrayVisitor count]; x++)
{
  if ([[[arrayVisitor objectAtIndex:x]objectForKey:(@"Gender")]isEqual:@"Female"])
     [[arrayVisitor objectAtIndex:x] addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Location",@"Japan",nil]];
}
```

Comment: This is a very strange way of doing things.  Why don't you just put a dictionary with multiple keys and values instead of 3 dictionaries each with one key and value?

Comment: Before trying to make iOS apps, you should 1. develop some common sense, 2. learn something about algorithms and data types, 3. learn C as well. Until then, there's no point in desperately trying to get things right, you won't succeed if you don't even have the slightest idea about resolving trivial problems like this. **Be patient.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of adding key value pair to array you need to use `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableArray *outerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[outerArray objectAtIndex:1]];
[mutableDict setObject:@"Japan" forKey:@"Location"];

[outerArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:mutableDict];
```

**Or using for loop as:------------------**

```
NSMutableArray *arrayVisitor=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int arrayLength=arrayVisitor.count;

for (int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[arrayVisitor objectAtIndex:i]];
    if ([[mutableDict valueForKey:@"Gender"] isEqualToString:@"Female"]) {
        [mutableDict setObject:@"Japan" forKey:@"Location"];
        [arrayVisitor replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mutableDict];
    }
}
```

**Note**:- It is not multidimensional array , it is Array of NSDictionary objects,It should look like this

```
Array=(
       {
           Name= Peter
           Gender= Male
       },
       {
           Name = Glenn
           Gender = Female
       },
       {
           Name = Richard
           Gender = Male
       }
     )
```

Comment: Thanks mate! You save my day. Ah..Right, it is actually an array of NSDictionary objects! Sorry for my noobiness~ Cheers :)